# DbContext Error: A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asynchronous

Im working with .NET Core 3.1 using Repository Pattern, sometimes I get this error
**A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads using the same instance of DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913.** in this method

I checked the link in the suggestion but still not working well

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<VentaPorPromotor>> GetVentaPorPromotor(DateTime fecha)
        {
            var creditos = await creditoRepository.FindAll().Where(c => c.Eliminado == false).ToListAsync();
            var colaboradores = await colaboradorRepository.FindAll().Where(c => c.Eliminado == false).ToListAsync();

            var ventasPorPromotor = (from credito in creditos
                                     join colaborador in colaboradores on credito.IdPromotor equals colaborador.Id
                                     where credito.FechaInicio == fecha
                                     group new { credito, colaborador } by colaborador.Nombres into colaboradores2
                                     orderby colaboradores2.Key
                                     select new VentaPorPromotor()
                                     {
                                         Nombre = colaboradores2.Key,
                                         Venta = colaboradores2.Sum(c => c.credito.MontoCredito),
                                         Creditos = colaboradores2.Count()

                                     }).ToList();

            return ventasPorPromotor;
        }
```

also I've tried in async way

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<VentaPorPromotor>> GetVentaPorPromotor(DateTime fecha)
        {
            var ventasPorPromotor = await (from credito in creditoRepository.FindAll()
                                           join colaborador in colaboradorRepository.FindAll() on credito.IdPromotor equals colaborador.Id
                                           where credito.FechaInicio == fecha
                                           group new { credito, colaborador } by colaborador.Nombres into colaboradores2
                                           orderby colaboradores2.Key
                                           select new VentaPorPromotor()
                                           {
                                               Nombre = colaboradores2.Key,
                                               Venta = colaboradores2.Sum(c => c.credito.MontoCredito),
                                               Creditos = colaboradores2.Count()

                                           }).ToListAsync();

            return ventasPorPromotor;
}
```

but I still getting the error

Comment: Don't use the repository pattern over EF, don't try to cache DbContexts. Your code would be faster more efficient, easier to read, less abstracted and would just work

Comment: That aside, your issue is likely what you are doing in that repository and how you are storing the DBContext. They are not thread safe, are naturally cached, and should be used in a using statement in single threaded contexts for small components of work.

Comment: Probably you have missed `await` call somewhere in other place.